# Require.js load timeout for jquery/underscore/backbone/parse modules

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, router

> Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: order!libs/jquery/jquery-min
>   order!libs/underscore/underscore-min order!libs/parse/parse-min
>   libs/jquery/jquery-min libs/underscore/underscore-min
>   libs/parse/parse-min Backbone 
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout

I have no 404 requests under the Network tab of Chrome, and I have no script errors, so I am outside of the common bugs/fixes for the problem (according to requirejs.org).

When I look at my Network, I see that the scripts are loaded in the following order:

```
require.js
main.js
app.js <-- required by main.js
order.js <-- used in main.js to require the next 4 scripts (which aren't AMD)
jquery-min.js <-- required by main.js
underscore-min.js <-- required by main.js
backbone-min.js <-- required by main.js
parse-min.js <-- required by main.js
router.js
login.js
text.js
```

This seems right to me. Below is my code for `main.js`,`app.js`, and `router.js`.

main.js:

```
// Author: Thomas Davis <thomasalwyndavis@gmail.com>
// Filename: main.js

// Require.js allows us to configure shortcut alias
// Their usage will become more apparent futher along in the tutorial.
require.config( {
    paths : {
        jQuery : 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
        Underscore : 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        Backbone : 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
        Parse : 'libs/parse/parse-min',
        templates : '../templates'
    }
});

require( [
    // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
    'app',

    // Some plugins have to be loaded in order due to their non AMD compliance
    // Because these scripts are not "modules" they do not pass any values to the
    // definition function below
    'order!libs/jquery/jquery-min',
    'order!libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    'order!libs/backbone/backbone-min',
    'order!libs/parse/parse-min'
],
function(App) {
    // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
    // Again, the other dependencies passed in are not "AMD" therefore
    // don't pass a parameter to this function
    App.initialize();
});
```

app.js:

```
// Filename: app.js
define( [ 'jQuery', 'Underscore', 'Parse', 'router' ],
function($, _, Parse, Router) {
    var initialize = function() {

        Parse.$ = $;

        // Initialize Parse with your Parse application javascript keys
        Parse.initialize("HIDDEN", "ALSO HIDDEN");

        // Pass in our Router module and call it's initialize function
        Router.initialize();
    };

    return {
        initialize : initialize
    };
});
```

router.js:

```
// Filename: router.js
define( [ 'jQuery', 'Underscore', 'Backbone', 'Parse', 'views/home/login', ],
function($, _, Backbone, Parse, loginView) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend( {
        routes : {
            // Default
            '*actions' : 'defaultAction'
        },
        defaultAction : function(actions) {
            // We have no matching route, lets display the home page
            loginView.render();
        }
    });

    var initialize = function() {
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize : initialize
    };
});
```

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I switched to loading the JS files outside of my `main.js` and in my `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: I get that this would work for you but this doesn't use requireJS to load the modules anymore so it doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: This pretty much goes against the principle of AMD.

Answer (score 1):

try use requirejs-jquery. It's version of requirejs is ready to work with jquery and try use shim config.

See this link: https://github.com/jrburke/require-jquery

Shim config example:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    "jqueryUI": "libs/jquery-ui",
    "jquery": "libs/jquery-1.9.1",
    "underscore": "libs/underscore-min",
    "backbone": "libs/backbone-min"
  },
  shim: {
    jqueryUI:{
         deps: ["jquery"],
         exports:"$"
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
      exports: "Backbone"
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just released an open source toolkit which will help with issues like this.  It is a composition of many open source tools which gives you a working requirejs backbone app out of the box.

It provides single commands to run: dev web server, jasmine single browser test runner, jasmine js-test-driver multi browser test runner, and concatenization/minification for JavaScript and CSS. It also outputs an unminified version of your app for production debugging, precompiles your handlebar templates, and supports internationalization.

No setup is required. It just works.

http://github.com/davidjnelson/agilejs